# C - segmentation fault and strlen

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to figure out this segmentation fault for hours. Every time I use the char* find I get a seg fault.

```
char* find = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

displayMatrix(rowcol, matrix);
// (Don't mind that ^^^)

printf("Enter a word to find in the puzzle : \n");
scanf("%s", &find);
tolower(find);
len = strlen(find) + 1;
```

When I run the program, it seg faults right as it gets to

```
len = strlen(find) + 1
```

Anyone know why it's doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you meant to use `scanf("%s", find);` probably.

Comment: `tolower()` Does not work like that. Either you disabled compiler warnings or, you ignore them. And there is no way that `sizeof(char) != 1` so don't use that.

Comment: Oh geez. I haven't been using -Wall this whole time. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Put a debug print between `scanf`, `tolower` and `len` of `printf("Here!\n");` and then see where the code is actually failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%s", &find);` should be `scanf("%s", find);` `find` is already the address of the string.

and `tolower` is incorrect, too: `int tolower ( int c );` not `int tolower ( char *c );`

Comment: You didn't catch the `tolower()`?

Comment: I think `char* find = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);`  is the correct way to allocate memory.

Comment: @nullpointer: this highly upvoted question with a highly upvoted answer says NOT to cast the result of malloc (in C, C++ is a different language): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @dave : Thanx for that.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do it would be point to a string literal using `const char *` and changing the rest of the code as:

```
const char* find = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
printf("Enter a word to find in the puzzle : \n");
scanf("%s", find);
printf("find says : I have got this saved under me %s \n", find); //just tried checking if it works
tolower(find); //this surely needs some correction,determine what you want
int len = strlen(find); //you won't require +1 using strlen
printf("%d : It Works Fine.",len);
```

Comment: Where do you find the need to cast the result of *malloc*?

Comment: @ringø referring to `void *malloc(size_t);` shouldn't I be doing that?

Comment: Well, google it. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for intance.

Comment: @ringø : thanx for that, leads to why for `char* find = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);` would CLion display `Incompatible pointer types 'char*' and 'void*'` ...shouldn't it be following such practice?